# Replacing certain number of characters in string with Regex or Gsub

Tags: json, r, regex

Couldn't find the right answer so I'd like to change the question.

I have a code in JSON that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "section_id": "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd2",
    "name": "Name1",
    "slug": "slug1"
  },
  {
    "section_id": "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd3",
    "name": "Name2",
    "slug": "slug2"
  },
  {
    "section_id": "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd4",
    "name": "Name3",
    "slug": "slug3",
    "categories": [
      {
        "section_id": "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd5",
        "name": "Name31",
        "slug": "slug31"
      },
      {
        "section_id": "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd6",
        "name": "Name32",
        "slug": "slug32",
        "categories": [
          {
            "section_id": "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd7",
            "name": "Name321",
            "slug": "slug321"
          },
          {
            "section_id": "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd8",
            "name": "Name322",
            "slug": "slug322"
          },
          {
            "section_id": "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd9",
            "name": "Name323",
            "slug": "slug323"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'd like to change every occurance of "section_id" with certain number of characters after it so that it could look like this:

```
{
    "section_id": { "$oid" : "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd2" },
    "name": "Name1",
    "slug": "slug1"
  }
```

Do you know how to change it with regex or some other way?

Comment: Tried converting JSON to character, then substr'inging certain number of characters after that but in character there are no { } brackets so it doesn't do the work for me. Thought about inserting the code to mongo database and then quering it to change string to objectId but didn't find any solution for this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have the JSON in an R string variable. This solution looks for the section_id key and alters everything up to the next comma.

```
cat(gsub('("section_id":\\s+)([^,]+),', '\\1{ "$oid" : \\2 },', JSON))
[
  {
    "section_id": { "$oid" : "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd2" },
    "name": "Name1",
    "slug": "slug1"
  },
  {
    "section_id": { "$oid" : "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd3" },
    "name": "Name2",
    "slug": "slug2"
  },
  {
    "section_id": { "$oid" : "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd4" },
    "name": "Name3",
    "slug": "slug3",
    "categories": [
      {
        "section_id": { "$oid" : "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd5" },
        "name": "Name31",
        "slug": "slug31"
      },
      {
        "section_id": { "$oid" : "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd6" },
        "name": "Name32",
        "slug": "slug32",
        "categories": [
          {
            "section_id": { "$oid" : "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd7" },
            "name": "Name321",
            "slug": "slug321"
          },
          {
            "section_id": { "$oid" : "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd8" },
            "name": "Name322",
            "slug": "slug322"
          },
          {
            "section_id": { "$oid" : "58ef93aaa310c97c0c16bcd9" },
            "name": "Name323",
            "slug": "slug323"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much, sir, for your kind help!